# Install package into live environment

Tags: apt, package-management, live-usb, live-cd, live-environment

Suppose one is running Ubuntu's live CD/DVD installer ISO. Now also suppose for whatever purpose, they need to install a package into that live environment (the in-RAM environment, not the ISO image). How does one do that? I've tried running `apt-get install` in the installer ISO's live environment and I receuved an error.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release; Ubuntu offers lots of ISOs that use different installers (four installers currently are offered).  However you just `sudo apt update` to let your system update your software repositories on what is available; then `sudo apt install` what you want... done.

Comment: @guiverc What do you mean?

Comment: I use *live* systems in QA very often... where I'm booting a *live* image (*unreleased in my case*) and use it as a normal system for a number of hours (*I can also open/close normal apps as per a testcase, but here I'm referring to live usage*) which requires me to to what I mentioned; ie. `sudo apt update` to update software lists to match current (*even a daily ISO maybe only a few hours old; but its mandatory for most ISOs anyway*) then `apt install` (or `snap install`) to install what I need to use it for myself in that session...  I'll need to repeat all of that if I use it next boot

Answer (score 1):

You just

`sudo apt update`

to let your system update your software repositories on what is available; then

`sudo apt install`

what you want... done.

You can also `snap install` too  :)

Comment: If you don't `apt update` to update software resources available on the internet; the system will only be aware of what exists on the *unstated* ISO itself that you're using; ie. its a rather limited subset of what is available online.

Comment: I have assumed a Desktop ISO here as you don't specify, this will work equally well on ISOs using `calamares`, `ubiquity` and `ubuntu-desktop-installer` as used by Ubuntu Desktop & *flavors* for various releases currently on offer.  Older releases using *di* weren't run *live* so they differed to what I've described here (The *debian installer* was last used for Desktop systems on 18.04 as an *alternate* ISO for low-RAM hardware for *flavors*)

Comment: FYI:  I perform *live* testing using Ubuntu.. and part of that includes booting the current *daily* image and then using that instead of an installed system for a number of hours as if it is my machine...  The software I use is not only the default packages included on ISO so I'm needing to add additional packages... Be aware there are limits to how far you can push a *live* system... as the space created for COW (copy on write) will eventually run out and the system can become unstable.. but you can learn to use it most efficiently if you need to.